# Get file name after async download is complete

Tags: vb.net

I did some Google search but couldn't find what I was looking for. I start multiple async downloads at the same time and I want to check which file is downloaded. How can I achieve this?

```
Private Sub client_DownloadCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs)

    MsgBox("Download Completed!") ' I want to add the name of the downloaded file in this message

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [AsyncCompletedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asynccompletedeventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) there is a property UserState. This way you can access data that you set when you start the async task. Just fill in the path in the UserState and use it.
To set the user data value, you can use this overload of [DownloadFileAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144197%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. How can I achieve this? When I am starting the process of the download? I start it with client.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(uri), fileName)

Comment: I assume that client is of type WebClient. There is another overload of the DownloadFileAsync method that takes a third Parameter. Call it like this: Client.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(uri), fileName, fileName). Then you should be able to use e.UserData in the Completed Event.